# How to retain all instances of of a single subclass from a general ArrayList

Tags: java

I'm having a problem and I can't figure out a clean solution.

I have this superclass "Creature" with subclasses "Human" and "Zombie"
I have constructed a series of humans and zombies and saved them in an ArrayList
Now I want to get the subArrayList that only contains the constructed humans.
I thought I could use the "retainAll" but it turns out it doesn't do what I thought it would do.

Any suggestions how to create a new ArrayList with only the objects of subclass Zombie in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `instanceof` operator. Try this code:

```
List<Human> humans = new ArrayList<Human>();
for (Creature creature : creatures) {
    if (creature instanceof Human) {
        humans.add((Human) creature);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
List<Zombie> zombies = 
    Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(creatures, Zombie.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate trough the elements, use instanceof and build a new arraylist. For this I would use Google Guava library

Answer (score 1):

take a look on the operator `instanceof`

Note: It is probably a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) if you need to filter a list based on the specific instance type - if you give more details on what you are trying to do - maybe there is a better way of achieving it, and [refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) your code

Comment: Thanks, instance was what I was looking for but it seems that a better way might be keeping seperate lists after all. The problem is that somewhere in the program I need to randomly select 1 guy from all the list so if I keep seperate list it gets biased :/

Comment: @user1193435 There are ways to handle this. for example, maintain two lists: one for zombies and one for humans. When you want to chose a random creature, chose a human with probability `humans.size() / (zombies.size() + humans.size())`. If you want more details on it - this is a different thing and you might want to ask a new question about it.

Comment: You mean a binomial with p[human] = [h.size / h.size + z.size]
succes=1 -> take a human
fail = 0 -> take a zombie

Comment: @user1193435 : yes, something like that, and when chosing a random human, you chose him at probability `P(h) = 1/h.size * (h.size / (h.size + z.size)) = 1/ (h.size + z.size)`, same for each zomby - so you get unbiased random choice. Though if it is more complex - it should be covered in a new question.

Comment: @user: A simpler/easier to understand way might be to simply generate a random index `index = random.nextInt(humans.size() + zombies.size())` and then select like so `Creature randomCreature = index >= humans.size() ? zombies.get(index-humans.size()) : humans.get(index);`  In other words, treat the two lists like one big list, choose a random index, and then work out the index for the actual sublist.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a very clean way to do this, only with instanceof and casts as mentioned by other answers.

If possible, I would suggest to keep seperate lists of each type, and merge the lists only when you need all the Creatures.